# CSV file append value from json value in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV like this

```
SKU     NAME          VALUE
```

```
123     PRODUCT-1     {"Size": "16x7", "PCD": "5x114.3", "Offset": "48"}
456     PRODUCT-2     {"Drill": "29-15", "Face": "Face-4", "Rim Type": "L Center"}
789     PRODUCT-3     {"Bore": "73.1", "Drill": "32-13", "Face": "Face-3"}
```

I would like to use python3 pandas to create into:

```
SKU     NAME          SIZE     PCD     OFFSET     DRILL     FACE     etc...
```

```
123     PRODUCT-1     16x7     5x114.3 48
456     PRODUCT-2                                 29-15     Face-4    etc...               
789     PRODUCT-3                                 32-13     Face-3    etc...
```

I tried to use pd.read_json and tolist() but I dont know where to go from there.  I really appreciate it if you can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the csv as normal then we convert it after loaded the data

```
df = pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv')
import ast 
df['VALUE'] = df['VALUE'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('VALUE').tolist(), index=df.index))
```